# Java DecimalFormat problem

Tags: java, decimal, locale

I would like to format numbers of type double with a German locale in Java. However something goes wrong since the output of the following code is : 0.0

```
package main;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Test {

    private static String decimal2Format = "000.000"; 

    public static void main(String args[]){
        DecimalFormat format = (DecimalFormat)NumberFormat.getInstance(new Locale("de"));
        double value = 0;
        try {
            format.applyPattern(decimal2Format);
            value = format.parse("0.459").doubleValue();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(value);
    }

}
```

Do you have any ideas what is wrong or missing?

Thanks,
   atticus

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're trying to parse using a pattern which will expect a comma (as it's in German) but you've given it a period ("0.459"). It looks like `DecimalFormat` stops parsing when it sees a character it doesn't understand. If you change it to "0,459" you'll see it parse correctly and then output "0.459". (I'm not sure whether `System.out.println` uses the system default locale, in which case it *might* print "0,459" depending on your locale.)

Note that you haven't tried to *format* the number at all in this code - only *parse* a number. If you want to format it, call format. The `double` itself doesn't have an associated format - it's just a number. It's not like parsing using a particular formatter returns a value which retains that format.

Here's code which will perform actual *formatting* of a double value:

```
DecimalFormat format = (DecimalFormat)NumberFormat.getInstance(new Locale("de"));
double value = 0.459;
String formatted = format.format(value);
System.out.println(formatted); // Prints "0,459"
```

EDIT: Okay, so it sounds like you're converting it from one format to another (from US to European, for example). That means you should probably use two different `DecimalFormat` objects - you *could* switch the locale between calls, but that sounds a bit grim to me.

I believe one way to parse and detect errors is to use the `parse` overload which takes a `ParsePosition` as well. Set the position to 0 to start with, and afterwards check that it's at the end of the string - if it isn't, that means parsing has effectively failed. I find it odd that there isn't a method which does this automatically and throws an exception, but I can't see one...

You may also want to set the parser to produce a `BigDecimal` instead of a `double`, if you're dealing with values which are more logically decimal in nature. You can do this with the `setParseBigDecimal` method.

Comment: Two things regarding this issue:

My goal is to parse, since I get the input as a String, so in fact I need to parse and and then format it. Then in this case I think I should use both parse and format methods, am I right?

One other thing with parsing is that I need it to parse a little bit different. I am using this in a validation module, so when I get a "234.a23" String then I don't want it to be "234.0" after the validation but I want a parse exception to signal that something went wrong. Do you know any class that would behave in this way, or should I implement my own validation?